# How to store rich text editor's state in a database that generalizes to both web and mobile apps?

Tags: database-design, wysiwyg, application-design

I would like to store rich text editor's state in a database in the form that is easy to process by both web and mobile apps.

Currently, I have a web app that uses a library for WYSIWYG editor.
The library can serialize the internal state to JSON string and thus I can store the data directly in a database.
But if I want to develop a mobile app in the future, the data format might not be easily handled by the library used in the mobile app.
So what is the best way to store the editor's state? Is it better to make an adapter for the mobile app that converts stored JSON data to whatever format that is easy to handle by the mobile app?